# EF6 StackOverflowException Code-First Migration MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, code-first

I'm getting a stackoverflow exception from EF6 Code-First Migration and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, or why this is being thrown.

So before, all of my ID's were regular sized INT's. We wanted the ability to store more data, so I created a migration to alter the columns of the database to shift them from INT to BIGINT.

Now, when I ran this I had no problems. However, the columns in my model were still reflected as INT. So I went and updated the columns from INT to LONG.

Now, when I run the program and it attempts to check if the database is migrated, it throws the exception.

```
 if (!Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
 {
    Database.Initialize(true);
 }
```

Here is an example of what I changed:

BEFORE

```
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

AFTER

```
[Key]
public long ID { get; set; }
```

And here is an example of the migration from Up()

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE table MODIFY COLUMN ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT");
```

I'm not sure of the proper way to add a new migration, I thought I had a good understanding of it but now I am confused. Should I change the model and then call Add-Migration "Name" or do I manually type what I want to do in the Up() function?

Also, from the PMC if I type 'Update-Database -Verbose' it prints out that it is reading my App.config, and immediately after throws the StackOverflowException

Comment: You'd usually change the model first and then call `Add-Migration` to have EF generate the `Up()` and `Down()` functions for you. You can adjust the generated functions if necessary, but you should never change the DB schema yourself. Only EF should manage that if you want to use its migration feature.

Comment: So when you say "change the model first" are you referencing the .CS files that are generated with your table name? If I attempt to change anything in those CS files, that is when it throws the stack overflow exception.

Comment: So the last item I did was added a new migration to move the ID columns from int to BIGINT, and that migration works and I can called Update-Database with no exceptions. The problem is, the files themselves still think its an "int" so I will have data loss if a number gets too big

Comment: Yea, I meant the C# model classes. But it seems you're actually doing EF with DB-first, instead of code-first like you said in the question. Not sure if migrations even work with DB-first. That appears non-sensical to me. You could try just deleting and regenerating all the code that EF generated for you, though.

Comment: I'm using code first. I think its because I changed the primary key from an INT to a BIGINT, and it got confused. I restarted my migrations with those changes, and had no issue creating a new migration.